# Prove non regularity of the language a^n where n is an even or a prime number, with the pumping lemma

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, pumping-lemma

How to prove that the language that is the union of the language where $n$ is an even number and the language where $n$ is a prime number is non-regular with the pumping lemma?

I know how to prove that the language $a^n$ where $n$ is a prime number is non-regular, but I'm struggling to prove the union.

Can anyone help me, please?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I think you forgot to mention how the initial languages (before the union) are constructed. (I think you mean $L_1 = \{ a^n : \text{n is even} \}$ and $L_2 = \{ a^n : \text{ n is prime } \}$.).

Comment: If $L_1\cup L_2$ were regular, so would be $(L_1\cup L_2)\setminus L_1$…

Comment: Hint: regular languages are closed under complement, intersection, and union. Use this to prove that if the language you described is regular, so is $\{a^n \mid n$ prime$\}$.